# How do i return true/false on get-content command for each username inside C:/Users?

Tags: command-line, powershell, script, csv

We want to eliminate the existence of a bad config file we've identified (and also have the manual fix for) from within every users appdata folder. The config file only exists here and there and not within every user. So I am trying to piece together a script that will return true/false if specified text is matched with get-content on config.xml. I want to run this against each user profile on every machine and output results to csv.

So far I've run into an issue. Still learning powershell so any help much appreciated.

```
$Users = "C:\Users"
$x = "This is the text I'm looking for"


Foreach ($Username in $Users)

{
$Path = "$Users\$Username\AppData\Local\MyApp\Settings\Config.xml"
$y = Get-Content -Path $Path
If ($y -match $x)

{
    "true"

}
else 
{
    "false"
}
}
```

As you can see i haven't gotten round to the csv part yet because I'm not able to get the correct path to generate for get-content.

Rather than having the correct path which I hoped as the foreach loop worked it's way through would be:

```
"C:\Users\Username1\AppData\Local\MyApp\Settings\Config.xml"
"C:\Users\Username2\AppData\Local\MyApp\Settings\Config.xml"
"C:\Users\Username3\AppData\Local\MyApp\Settings\Config.xml"
```

I am instead getting the following error:

```
Get-Content : Cannot find path 'C:\Users\C:\Users\AppData\Local\MyApp\Settings\Config.xml' because it does not exist.
At C:\Users\mastaxx\Desktop\test.ps1:9 char:6
+ $y = Get-Content -Path $Path
+      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (C:\Users\C:\Use...ings\Config.xml:String) [Get-Content], ItemNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PathNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetContentCommand
```

My seemingly silly assumption here is that $Users would be `"C:\Users"` (which i believe it is because I've defined it) and $Username would be `"Username1"` (which clearly it is not). Instead I can see it's also `"C:\Users"` in this case, making the path being constructed to be this incorrect one:

`C:\Users\C:\Users\AppData\Local\MyApp\Settings\Config.xml`

I expected the foreach loop to treat each folder inside `$Users` as an individual object and become the `$Username` in each loop instance, allowing me to insert it into the config file `$path` like so:

```
$Users   $Username
  ↓          ↓
C:\Users\Username1\AppData\Local\MyApp\Settings\Config.xml
```

I'm not entirely sure what i'm doing wrong but i know I'm definitely doing something silly here. Would very much appreciate anyone with better PS skills to help point it out?

Comment: This is not clear. Config files from what Application?   Finding User Profile errors is probably next to impossible.

Comment: We know the manual fix for this and have been going around trashing the culprit config file and allowing the  application to rebuild it from scratch on next launch. I've deliberately left out the application name for business purposes. All i want the script to do is match the text specified in $text and if true export config file user path to csv. This will allow me to go round all those user profiles over the weekend and apply to manual fix to each one. Which beats checking every single workstation individually.

Comment: Sorry i meant to say $x not $text

Comment: I've come closer to working this out. Might post an answer to my own question soon

Comment: I've worked it out. I was missing get-childitem from the equation. After adding that in i was able to use `foreach ($folder in Get-Childitem $users)` to have the foreach loop to work against each user folder.

Comment: You should post the answer (that worked) to an actual answer on your post since you are allowed to answer your own questions you ask too.  It could be helpful to future reading have the same issue you explain here.

Comment: Thanks @Vomit IT - Chunky Mess Style - I've now posted my answer!

Comment: I hope you realize your script needs admin-rights and elevation on every computer you are going to run it on, in order to be able to do anything with other users profiles. And that the config-file you want to delete or change may be locked if the user has the application open. Placing your code in the login-script and only run it for the current user may be a better solution.

Comment: Thanks Tonny. I have domain admin privileges so I'm able to run it without elevating. Also, the task of deleting the bad config file still remains a manual one. This is just to identify a bad line in the config file and spit out a CSV to tell us which machine it is and which user profile. As you say, we can only delete the config file if it's not in use, so we have to manually go through the list and make sure the users aren't logged in first. A weekend job basically!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've managed to work out that i was missing Get-Childitem in the equation.

This is the correct way to do it, although I'm sure my PS is in need of major improvement, as I was unable to get a properly formatted CSV to export so I opted for the messy approach which was to output an individual CSV for each instance of true, but at least it works!

```
$computers = Get-Content -Path "C:\computers.txt"



foreach ($comp in $computers) {

$i = "\\$comp\C$\Users\"
$AppData = "\AppData\Local\MyApp\Settings\Config.xml"
$text = "Text I'm Looking For*"



Get-ChildItem -Path $i
Foreach ($folder in Get-Childitem $i)
{

$ReadConfig = Get-Content -Path "$i$folder$AppData"
If ($ReadConfig -match $text)

{
  
  out-file "c:\results\$comp $folder.csv"
  
}
else 
{
    "false"
}
}
}
```